# Cowboy - как отправить 2 файла используя cowboy_static handler

Tags: erlang

Я хочу отправить html файл, который включает в себя таблицу стилей. Текущий код отправлет только html, как я могу модиицировать код для отправки обоих html и сss файлов находящихся в разных дирикториях?

```
 start(_StartType, _StartArgs) ->
    Dispatch = cowboy_router:compile([
        {'_', [{"/", cowboy_static, {
            priv_file, my_app, "static/index.html"}}}]}
    ]),
    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(my_http_listener,
        [{port, 8080}],
        #{env => #{dispatch => Dispatch}}
    ),
    my_app_sup:start_link().
```

P.S.: решение с prive_dir не подходит, так как index.html будет доступен только по url localhost:8080/index.html, моя же задача отобразить его по localhost:8080/